# How to set a new field in django models based on another field in another model?

Tags: django

I have a model like this:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name=_('status'))
    ...
```

and another model like this:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(to=Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

I want to remove the `status` field from `Foo` and add it to `Bar`.
But this is a new field and must be filled with a value.
I want to fill it with the status value in `bar_obj.foo` which is supposed to be deleted.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in two steps:

## Step 1: add the field and a *data migration*

first add the field to the `Bar` model:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(to=Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name=_('status'), default=0)
```

It's important to give the field a default value, or make it `null=True` in this stage, such that we can temporarily give the field values.

If we then run make migrations, it will make a migration. We will alter the migration, and add a [*data migration* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to it:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
from django.db.models import F


def copy_values(apps, schema_editor):
    # We can't import the Person model directly as it may be a newer
    # version than this migration expects. We use the historical version.
    Bar = apps.get_model('app_name', 'Bar')
    Bar.objects.update(status=F('foo__status'))


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [('app_name', '0123_prev_migration')]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            "Bar", "status", models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(copy_values),
    ]
```

I would suggest that you migrate this migration and check if the data is valid.

## Step 2: remove the status field on `Foo`

Next we can remove the `status` field from the `Foo` model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    …
    #  status = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(verbose_name=_('status'))
```

we can also remove the `default=…` value from the `status` field on `Bar` if necessary.

We make another migration and we can migrate.